# Converting RTL epub to mobi

Tags: conversion, epub, mobi

I have a Hebrew ebook in `epub` format; I would like to convert it to `mobi`, since I read exclusively on my Kindle. Hebrew reads right-to-left.

Kindle supports Hebrew ebooks (I have often used [Tinderizer](http://tinderizer.com/) to send Hebrew articles to my Kindle). I tried converting this ebook to `.mobi` using Calibre, the book looked fine in Calibre's `View specific format` preview window, but on my actual Kindle device, the RTL-format was messed up - each word was readable (individual characters RTL as expected), but the words themselves were in the wrong order (LTR).

Is there a way I can convert my file into a readable `.mobi` file?

Comment: I converted from pdf to azw3, and the email with which I sent it to my kindle account got bounced back. Why didn't it work for me?

Comment: @ScottSpiegler: Welcome to the EBooks Stack Exchange (SE) site! The SE sites are not a typical forum format where posts follow a conversation format. Rather answers should directly address the original poster's question. I have converted your answer to a comment (alternatively you could ask your own question). Please check out the 2 minute help tour http://ebooks.stackexchange.com/tour and feel free to explore the help in more detail http://ebooks.stackexchange.com/help. There is also a chat site better suited for conversational style q/a http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12058/the-appendix

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[According to Kovid Goyal](https://bugs.launchpad.net/calibre/+bug/1073414) ( creator of Calibre) you need to convert to azw3 instead of mobi.